# How to show page by order in Post Query Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to show page in a custom template. I use post query loop to show the page and it works. But I donot want the home page to show. and I want to show my pages by ASCENDING order. I use order in pages.But I am not able to fix it.

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'page', 'order' => 'ASC');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
if (!empty($myposts)) :
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <section class="col-1-3">
                <div class="wrap-col">
                        <div class="box">
                                <div>
                                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                        <figure><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/page1_img1.jpg" alt="" ></figure>
                                        <p class="pad_bot1"><?php echo excerpt('20'); ?>...</p>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button1">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </section>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else : ?>
        default data
<?php endif; ?>
```

can you please help me to out of this.

Comment: You want to remove home page to display?

Comment: yes I want to remove form the list and show other pages by ascending orders as I use order in pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a front page set in Settings > Reading. If that is the case, this should work for you:

```
$front_page = get_option( 'page_on_front' );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post__not_in'   => array( $front_page ),
);
```

Comment: Try asking in plugin's support page. I've never used it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude home page by passing home page id:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'page', 'order' => 'ASC','exclude' => 1);
```

Comment: you missing " , " between order and exclude :)

Comment: $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'page', 'order' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '1');

I use this but no change here.1 is the order number

Comment: Does "exclude" parameter really exist ?

Comment: Yes exclude parameter is exist. you can check here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

You Can right simple query also : put below code ( replace the table-name and field ) in your custom page

```
<?php

    global $wpdb;

    $customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM yourtablename Where id = 1 ORDER BY `yourtablename`.`date` ASC"); 

    // add code to limit / exclude ..  what you want 

    echo "<table>";
    foreach($customers as $customer){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$customer->title."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$customer->desc."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$customer->url."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: i cannot understand this

Comment: its simple PHP/ MYSQL format .. you can right your own query and fetch the record from multiple tables ... above is just example